# Tkinter Button text invisible until window resize

Tags: python, python-3.x, button, tkinter

I have Python 3.6.3. I'm trying to program a simple GUI app with Submit and Quit buttons. I've got this GUI code:

```
from tkinter import *
from sys import exit

...

some = True
stuff = False
here = "bar"

top = Tk()

submitButton = Button(top, text="Submit", command=lambda: submit(some, things, set, here)).pack(pady=50, side=LEFT)
exitButton = Button(top, text="Quit", command=exit).pack(pady=50, side=RIGHT)

top.mainloop()
```

However, upon running this code, my button labels are invisible:

[image: Invisible buttons]

And I need to resize the window, even only a little, in order to see them again:

[image: The restored buttons. Note a slightly bigger window.]

Am I doing something wrong here, or is this a bug with tkinter?

Comment: Does it do this with default padding (0)?

Comment: Can't reproduce, the gui appears correctly (OSX)

Comment: BTW, `.pack` returns `None`, so you aren`t actually binding your Button widgets to those names.

Comment: Works for me on ubuntu

Comment: Tested in Windows 7. Works fine.

Comment: @TheoC Quick side note you do not need to import exit. You can use the `destroy()` method on your root window as it is built into tkinter.

Comment: @PM2Ring I changed that but it still didn't work. Also, if that is the case, why did the widgets still show up?

Comment: @DanielGale Yes.

Comment: @Mike-SMT Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to imply that was the cause of your problem, it's just an incidental issue. The code works because you never do anything with `submitButton` or `exitButton` after those assignments, so it doesn't matter that they're `None`. But if you add to that code and try to access those widgets with those names it won't work.

Comment: @PM2Ring I see, no worries.

Comment: FWIW, your buttons show up fine for me on Python 3.6.0, Tkinter 8.5 on Linux. (I couldn't test it before because I was on my phone). Another BTW, don't use `set` as a variable name because that shadows the built-in `set` type, which can cause mysterious error messages if you later try to use it to construct a set.

Comment: @PM2Ring I didn't use `set` as a variable name, they were examples. `some things set here`

Comment: @PM2Ring Sure, fixing now.

Comment: @TheoC how did you fix it?

Comment: I'm struggling with same problem. Did you fixed it?

Comment: Have you tried using the .geometry() method ?? Anyways I tried this on Windows 10 and ElementaryOS, it worked fine..

Answer (score 0):

Add an update call before your mainloop call.

```
top.update()
top.mainloop()
```

Also consider upgrading to python3.7, since a lot of tkinter problems for mac were fixed in 3.7.

Comment: This doesn't help, I added `top.update()` right before it but no change.